# Unenable the automatic title in forecast plot

Tags: r, forecasting

In the forecast package how can I unenable from the forecast plot the automatic title which shows the information for the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `main` argument in the `plot` function (sets the "Main title" of the plot). Using the example at `?plot.forecast`:

```
# with title (default)
deaths.fit <- hw(USAccDeaths, h = 48)
plot(deaths.fit)

# remove title. `""` is an empty character string
plot(deaths.fit, main = "")
```

See also `?title` for examples of how to specify your own title.